# Rotate image if width is greater than a value (i.e in pixels)

Tags: bash, shell-script, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I was trying to rotate few hundred images which have 7000px height in 1000+ images how to rotate them from bash.

Answer (score 3):

You can analyse the size of the picture using ImageMagick's `identify` and then rotate it using ImageMagick's `convert` commandline tool.

```
pic=file.jpg
height=$(identify ${pic} | sed 's/.*x\([0-9]\+\)\+.*/\1/g')

if [[ $height -gt 7000 ]]; then
  convert ${pic} -rotate 90 ${pic}_rotated
fi
```

The second line extract the height from the output of indentify. The `if`-clause check if that value is greater than 7000 and then rotates the image 90°.

Comment: No need for `sed`, just user `-format` option to output only image height: `identify -format "%h"`